# RxJS merge observables but prefer one over the other

Tags: rxjs

I have two observables `A` and `B`, and I'd like to create an observable which emits the latest value from `B`, but if `B` hasn't emitted anything yet, it emits the latest value from `A`. I was thinking something like this:

```
merge(A.takeUntil(B), B)
```

But this seems a little counterintuitive, and I'd like to have a more readable approach. Is there a more canonical Rx way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you will find a more readable solution. Anyway, in this solution you subscribes to B twice, so better to share the observable B before: `sharedB = B.share(); merge(A.takeUntil(sharedB), sharedB);`

Comment: Additionally, you could `concat` instead of `merge`.  This makes it clearer that you do intend to wait out the first Observable:
```const sharedB = B.share();
Rx.Observable.concat(A.takeUntil(sharedB), sharedB);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom Operator

This solution is very readable in use but complicated by the fact that you hide the complexity within a custom operator. The benefit of a custom operator is that you only subscribe to each source observable once. This means your observables don't have to be "hot".

Unfortunately, this operator breaks synchronously executing observables and has each value pass through the event loop.

```
function prefer<T, R>(...observables: Observable<R>[]): Observable<R>{
  return new Observable(observer => {

    const subscrptions = new Array<Subscription>();
    const unsub = (index) => {
      for(let i = index; i < subscrptions.length; i++){
        subscrptions[i].unsubscribe();
      }
    }

    observables
      .map(stream => publish()(stream))
      .forEach((stream, index) => {
        subscrptions.push(stream.subscribe((payload: R) => {
          observer.next(payload);
          unsub(index + 1);
          subscrptions.length = index + 1;
        }));
        stream.connect();
      });

    return { unsubscribe: () => unsub(0) }
  })
}
```

#### Operator in Use

```
prefer(
  interval(10000).pipe(map(_ => "Every 10,000")),
  interval(5000).pipe(map(_ => "Every 5,000")),
  interval(1000).pipe(map(_ => "Every 1,000")),
  interval(250).pipe(map(_ => "Every 250"))
).subscribe(console.log);
```